# Acer Aspire One 722-0369 Flaky Ethernet Connection

Tags: 13.04, networking, drivers, acer, ethernet

I have an Acer Aspire One 722 Netbook running Ubuntu 13.04. It has a "Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet" Ethernet controller.
 When I connect to the internet via a WiFi connection it works great. But sometimes don't have access to WiFi and must use  a wired ethernet connection. When I use an ethernet connection, the internet connection seems to be flaky. About half of the time webpages will load. I have to keep reloading the page until it works.

Comment: is this on a home network? at work or a college?

Comment: Mostly a home network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been reported. You can check it's status at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1175091). There appears to be no workaround.